# Full Plone (folder) backup

Tags: python, plugins, backup, plone, plone-4.x

I'm looking for a solution to make a full Plone backup: from Python folder (installed packages) to plugins and blobstorage, filestorage.

I've found this, from official documentation: http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/backup.html

but it says anything about, for example, plugins backup.

**edit**

For now, it seems that the only solution is to copy the entire Plone folder and restore data and blob backups

Comment: Just use any software backup solution for the code, there is nothing special about that part.

Comment: Almost all plugins store their data in the Zope DB - if not it should be obvious from their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mainstream way to achieve this is by having:

1. a data backup (use [collective.recipe.backup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.backup/))
2. a buildout backup (storing it in a version control system like git or SVN).

However in some special case you could like a full backup.
This is especially true if you need to restore an old legacy buildout years after its creation. In that case using the canonical way you can encounter a lot of issues like add-ons disappeared from pypi, distribute/setuptools/zc.buildout hells, ...

In that case a full folder backup can works if you restore the backup in a machine ideally equal to the original ones (this can be easy in a virtual environment) **and** keeping original FS path.

Note: if you are in a virtual environment, a full machine backup can be also easier.

Comment: And exclude the Data.fs from your backup, if you use the collective.recipe.backup to make incremental-/full backups. Otherwise you backup to much data.

Comment: Right, also blob files can be omitted.